# Parallel testing with Selenium Grid (using C# unit tests)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

**Following AutomatedTesters response:** Is there any way to run parrallel tests with C# code, without using class libraries other than the Selenium Core?

---

I have the following setup:

Selenium Grid Hub: 192.168.0.1
Selenium RC 1 : 192.168.0.2
Selenium RC 2 : 192.168.0.3

Both remote controls are running *firefox. If only 1 of the remote controls is running, when I send a test to the hub it loads and runs fine. However if BOTH remote controls are running - the test only runs on one of them.

I was expecting that this:-

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("192.168.0.1", 4444, "*firefox", "http://blah.com/");
selenium.Start();
// rest of test follows...
```

would fire up BOTH remote controls at the same time?

Any ideas why this isn't happening?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having a look around and I think the answer for me is [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) and it's test runners

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately doing that will never have 2 Selenium instances running. Each Selenium object will control a browser and each browser will be started from 1 RC connected to an RC.

If you want to have it running multiple browsers in parallel you will need to run your tests with something like [PNunit](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5.7) or [MBunits Parallelizable](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/03/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-v306.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't understand the use of the Selenium Grid hub then if to manage parallel RCs you need a third-party program?

Comment: Selenium grid is a infrastructure of Selenium RC that supports running tests concurrently. So if you fire 5 tests in parallel at the Hub it will redirect the requests to the relevant RC. Using a 3rd party tool you can then setup which browsers it will/will not work against.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, appreciate the help